# connection timed out while reading ssm parameter in Lambda

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, networking, lambda

I have a lambda that it is vpce enabled to read secure string ssm paramater.

I have created vpc endpoint for ssm to establish private connectivity.

I'm getting this error Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/", even though I can access the ssm parameter via ec2 instance.

python code:

```
ssmp='testssm'
config = Config(retries=dict(max_attempts=3, mode='standard'))
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', config=config)
fx= ssm_client.get_parameter(
    Name=ssmp,
    WithDecryption=True
)
```

is there any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You would want to check from whom does the security group attached to the VPC Endpoint allow traffic. You most likely allow traffic only from another security group which the one attached to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Add HTTPS(443) Inbound Rule to security groups associated with the VPC Endpoint.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi, this is right but for outbound rule it is set to 0.0.0.0\0 destination , how can I limit cidr ip to resources on account cidr only. I added vpc and subnets cidr but connection timeout on endpoint keeps showing

Comment: `0.0.0.0\0` means allow outbound traffic to everywhere. I don't recommend messing with this. Your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi the issue is resolved by attaching correct SG, however I need to restrict outbound rules to specific cidr other than everywhere. how can I trace what the lambda trying to reach to? I added vpc and subnets cidr but still getting connection error.

Comment: Lambda is trying to reach out to the IP address of this host `ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. You can find that by using a [`dig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) command from an EC2 instance from the same network in which the lambda is operating. Technically, if you are sure you are using the VPC Endpoint, this IP address should be from your VPC, so the CIDR of the VPC should work. At this point I'm really confused what you are trying to achieve. As I said, I don't recommend restricting outbound traffic, usually this is not a security issue.